# Moving one end of a Phaser.Graphics line

Tags: phaser-framework

For a project I'm trying to draw a moving line in Phaser. I initially drew it using `game.debug.geom(line)`, but that is not really the right way to do it, since it doesn't allow for styling, and because the debugger takes a toll in performance.

Reading the docs, it seems to me that the way to do it would be with a `Phaser.Graphics` object, but I haven't been able to get it to work. As an example, I tried making a line move as the hand of a clock, with one end fixed and the other moving around it.

I thought it would be fine to create the `Graphics` object in the middle and then in `update` use [`reset`](http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.4/Phaser.Graphics.html#reset) to clear it and bring it back to the center, and then [`lineTo`](http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.4/Phaser.Graphics.html#lineTo) to make the rest of the line. But instead what I get is a line coming outwards from the centre, and then a ring.

Picture for sadness:

[image: What I have]

I made a [pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yeKaPp) with my attempts. The code is repeated below. What I would like to have is a line (lines?) coming from the center of the circle to the points in the circumference.

Is a `Graphics` object the best way to do that? How do I do it?

```
Demo.prototype = {
  create: function() {
    this.graphics = game.add.graphics(
      game.world.centerX,
      game.world.centerY
    );
    this.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0xffd900);
    this.counter = 0;
    this.step    = Math.PI * 2 / 360;
    this.radius  = 80;
  },
  update: function() {
    this.graphics.reset(
      this.game.world.centerX,
      this.game.world.centerY
    );
    var y = this.radius * Math.sin(this.counter);
    var x = this.radius * Math.cos(this.counter);
    this.graphics.lineTo(x, y);
    this.counter += this.step;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally understood that the coordinates taken by the `Phaser.Graphics` object are local, respective to the object's internal coordinate system. Using `moveTo(0, 0)` has the desired result of moving the object's drawing pointer back to its origin (and not, as I initially thought, to the origin of the game world). Using `reset(0, 0)`, on the other hand, would have the effect of moving the object's origin to the world's origin.

As for deleting the previous lines, the only method I've found is to manually clear the object's `graphicsData` Array (short of calling `destroy()` and creating an entirely new object, which is probably not a very good idea).

Replacing the code in the original question with this does the trick:

```
Demo.prototype =  {
  create: function() {
    this.graphics = game.add.graphics(
      game.world.centerX,
      game.world.centerY
    );
    this.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0xffd900);
    this.counter = 0;
    this.step    = Math.PI * 2 / 360;
    this.radius  = 80;
  },
  update: function(){
    // Erases the previous lines
    this.graphics.graphicsData = [];

    // Move back to the object's origin
    // Coordinates are local!
    this.graphics.moveTo( 0, 0 );

    var y = this.radius * Math.sin(this.counter);
    var x = this.radius * Math.cos(this.counter);
    this.graphics.lineTo(x, y);
    this.counter += this.step;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out this Phaser game called [Cut It](http://www.circusmoth.co.uk/05.15/cutit/) (not my game btw, found it [here](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/14923-phaser-cut-it/)).

It also draws a variable length dotted line by cleverly using the `Phaser.TileSprite`, and then changing its width.

[TileSprite](http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.4/Phaser.TileSprite.html) draws a repeating pattern, and you can use this to draw a line by drawing one bitmap of a linepart segment, use that as background of the TileSprite and make the height of the TileSprite the same as the height of the bitmap.

You can take a look at the game's source code, it's compressed and minified but still somewhat readable. You can look for the variable called `cut_line`.

Comment: That's an interesting pointer. I'll keep this in mind in the future, but as you can see in my own answer, I managed to do what I wanted with the `Graphics` object. If you have some info on why a `TileSprite` is preferable, then I might accept this answer instead.